# On my windows machine pymeshlab showing this error ERROR:root:'pymeshlab.pmeshlab.MeshSet' object has no attribute 'generate_boolean_difference'

Tags: python, open3d, pymeshlab

when I am trying to run the python script on my widows machine which same script is running without any error the code bellow giving me the pymeshlab not having the generate_boolean_difference error

```
ms = pymeshlab.MeshSet()
ms.load_new_mesh(meshFile)
ms.generate_boolean_difference(first_mesh=0,second_mesh=1)
```

is it the problem of windows? if yes how to solve this issue?